# rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/matchers/method_missing.rb:9:in `method_missing'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-expectations

I'm running RSpec tests and I got an error message saying: *undefined local variable or method `applicant_signup_path'*. This is strange because that *applicant_signup_path*  is working elsewhere in the test)

When I traced the error it looks like it's somehow related rspec-expectations, method_missing.rb:9:in `method_missing'

```
jyrki@ubu:~/rails_projects/p4$ bundle exec rspec -b spec/requests/applicant_signup_spec.rb
......F.....

Failures:

  1) ApplicantSignup signup with valid information after email URL validation, part I with the right activation key 
     Failure/Error: before { visit applicant_signup_path }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `applicant_signup_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2::Nested_2::Nested_2::Nested_1:0xbb88fac>
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-expectations-2.13.0/lib/rspec/matchers/method_missing.rb:9:in `method_missing'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:171:in `method_missing'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:398:in `method_missing'
     # ./spec/requests/applicant_signup_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:237:in `instance_eval'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:237:in `instance_eval'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:21:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:66:in `block in run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:66:in `each'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:66:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:418:in `run_hook'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:334:in `run_before_each_hooks'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:300:in `run_before_each'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:113:in `block in run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `call'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `call'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:418:in `run_hook'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:329:in `run_around_each_hooks'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
     # /home/jyrki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

Finished in 1.78 seconds
12 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/applicant_signup_spec.rb:77 # ApplicantSignup signup with valid information after email URL validation, part I with the right activation key
```

My Ruby version is 2.1.0 and Gemfile is below

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'

# state machine
gem 'state_machine', '1.2.0'

# Use PostgreSQL as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.17.0'

group :development, :test do 
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1' #'2.11.0'
    #gem 'minitest', '~> 5.3.1'
end

group :development do 
    gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
    gem "annotate", "~> 2.4.1.beta"
end 

group :assets do 
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.4.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
end 

group :test do 
    gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.2'
    gem 'rb-inotify', '~> 0.9.0'
    gem 'libnotify', '0.5.9'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
end 

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0.0'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.2.0'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0.0'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', require: false
end
```

Routes file (the beginning of the file)

```
P4::Application.routes.draw do


  resources :applicants
  resources :applicant_sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  resources :employers 

  resources :employer_sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/applicant_signup', to: 'applicants#new', via: 'get'
  match '/applicant_signin', to: 'applicant_sessions#new', via: 'get'
  match '/applicant_signout', to: 'applicant_sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'

  match '/employer_signup', to: 'employers#new', via: 'get'
  match '/employer_signin', to: 'employer_sessions#new', via: 'get'
  match '/employer_signout', to: 'employer_sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
```

Test file **applicant_signup_spec.rb** that creates the error

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "ApplicantSignup" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do 
     before { visit applicant_signup_path }

     it { should have_selector( 'h1', text: 'Sign up') }
     it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do 
    before { visit applicant_signup_path } #this creates the problem but not on the first run

    let(:submit) { "Create my account"}

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create an applicant" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(Applicant, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      #let(:applicant) { create_random_applicant }
      before do
        @email_random_part = Random.new.rand(10000..99999999).to_s
        @email = "bart@test" + @email_random_part + ".sun"
        fill_in "First name", with: "Bart"
        fill_in "Last name", with: "Simpson"
        fill_in "Email", with: @email
        fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create an applicant" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(Applicant, :count).by(1)
      end

      #Welcome page
      describe "welcome page" do

        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Welcome") }

        #Name
        #it { should have_content( "Bart") }

        it { should_not have_content( "Sign out") }

        it { Applicant.find_by_email(@email).can_activate?.should eq(true) }
      end

       #after email URL validation 
      describe "after email URL validation, part I" do

        before { click_button submit }  #sign_up first

        describe "with the right activation key" do

          let(:app) { Applicant.find_by_email(@email) }
          let(:new_app) { NewApplicant.find_by_applicant_id!(app.id) }

          before do 
            get "/validate_app", :validate_app => {:key => new_app.activation_key }
            #visit validate_app_path
            #app_sign_in app
          end

#The line below creates the error#
          it { new_app.activation_key.should_not eq(nil) }  #Error, Error `method_missing' !!

        end
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information, part 2" do
      #let(:applicant) { create_random_applicant }
      before do
        @email_random_part2 = Random.new.rand(10000..99999999).to_s
        @email2 = "bart@test" + @email_random_part2 + ".sun"
        fill_in "First name", with: "Bart"
        fill_in "Last name", with: "Simpson"
        fill_in "Email", with: @email2
        fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create an applicant" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(Applicant, :count).by(1)
      end

      #after email URL validation 
      describe "after email URL validation, part II " do

        before { click_button submit }  #sign_up first

        describe "with the wrong activation key" do

          let(:app2) { Applicant.find_by_email(@email2) }
          let(:new_app2) { NewApplicant.find_by_applicant_id!(app2.id) }

          before do
            visit validate_app_path, :key => "wrong-key" 
          end


          it { should have_selector('title', text: "Error") }

          it { should have_content( "Error") }

          it { Applicant.find_by_id(app2.id).can_disable?.should eq(false) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does your `spec_helpers.rb` file include this line: `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`. If not, RSpec doesn't know how to handle Rails named routes.

Comment: @Chiperific Thanks a lot! Your suggestion helped to solve the problem. If you make your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `spec_helpers.rb` file needs to include this line so RSpec has access to named routes:

`Config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Otherwise you can't use named routes and you'll have to provide urls.